# Unable to access webmin?

Tags: webmin

I'm unable to access webmin via web or com. I've changed the port, and I'm thinking it's the firewall that is closing it. What code is needed to change and give access to the port?

Answer (score 1):

First, reset the port to 10000 for Webmin by editing `/etc/webmin/miniserv.conf` putting 10000 in the `port` and `listen` fields. Save the changes. You should now be able to access Webmin through the standard web address.

Go into the Webmin Configuration page and add the new port you want to access through in the "Listen on IP's and ports:" section; leave the standard port 10000 open for now - you can add a second port in the settings. Make sure the "Open new ports in firewall" box is checked. Save the changes and try accessing Webmin through the new port. If that works, you can remove the port 10000 entry and use the new port.

If you are going to be accessing Webmin from outside of your LAN, make sure to add a port forwarding rule in your router for the new port.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, webmin uses port 10000. If you're running webmin on localhost you would have to enter the address localhost:10000 in the address bar of the browser.

If you are accessing a different computer you switch out localhost with that computer's IP address. If you have to open up a port in the firewall, I'm guessing it's port 10000.

Comment: I change the Webmin Port so its not 10000. It will not launch from com or browser. That's why I was asking for the command to open iptables so I could allow accesss if it's closed.